Vue <Calendar> component convert date to another format yyyy/mm/dd
below is my <Calendar>:
<Calendar
    v-model="value"
    :date-format="props.dateFormat"
    :view="props.view"
    :input-class="props.inputClass"
    show-icon
/>

my goal is to have my v-model output a yyyy-mm-dd format but I am having a hard time figuring out how I am able to achieve this.
If I try to do something like create a function for formatting and add it to the v-model, it will show the error "'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS"
To test, I can simply add {{ value }} to show what the v-model is outputting. It always gives the full date format like: "Fri Jun 07 2024 00:00:00 GMT +0900"
How will I be able to format the date and then add it to the "v-model"? what I tried may seem lacking but I seriously have no clue how to proceed with this issue.

Where's the calendar from?

Whatever component that is, if it's a typical vue library, it will have excellent documentation that will tell you all you need to know - what I tried may seem lacking - yes, it's lacking any evidence that you tried anything at all

It's hard to answer exactly without further information (libs etc.)
v-model directives are used to bind an exact value (such as a Date) to a component. Therefore binding a function is meaningless.
Since there exists date-format prop, I suggest you try this:
<Calendar
    v-model="value"
    :date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"
    :view="props.view"
    :input-class="props.inputClass"
    show-icon
/>


Why do you post an answer then?
